# GmailR Sending data.frame in body of email

Tags: r

I want to send data.frame data in body of email using gmailR. I tried htmlTable for the same.
    msg = htmlTable(data,rnames=FALSE)

```
html_bod <- paste0("<p> This is a test email. </p>", msg)

# sending mail
use_secret_file("/Users/abhishekgupta/Downloads/gmailR.json")



msg = htmlTable(data,rnames=FALSE)

html_bod <- paste0("<p> This is a test email. </p>", msg)

# sending mail
use_secret_file("/Users/abhishekgupta/Downloads/gmailR.json")



test_email <- mime(
  To = "1234@gmail.com",
  From = "1234@pharmeasy.in",
  Subject = "Data City Wise",
  body = html_bod,
  html =TRUE)

send_message(test_email)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `html_body()` instead of the `body` argument.

Load the packages:

```
library(gmailr)
library(tableHTML)
```

Create an HTML table using `tableHTML`:

```
msg = tableHTML(mtcars)
```

Add a paragraph before the table:

```
html_bod <- paste0("<p> This is a test email. </p>", msg)
```

Create a `MIME` message and send it:

```
mime() %>%
  to("1234@gmail.com") %>%
  from("1234@pharmeasy.in") %>%
  subject("Data City Wise") %>% 
  html_body(html_bod) %>% 
  send_message()
```

This is how the email looks like in gmail:

[image: gmail_output]

Comment: can we send the same mail to multiple mail ids ??

Comment: yes, just provide the email address as a vector, e.g. `to(c("person1@gmail.com", "person2@gmail.com"))`

Comment: html_bod <- paste0("<p> This is a test email. </p>", msg) . If i want to add a variable that changes continuously after "This is a test email"in the same line is it possible ?

Comment: Yep, just put it into paste!

Comment: is there any way we can build bar chart of the table and attach it in mail along with table ?

Comment: there probably is, but this sounds very much like a new question.